# Minimizing norm subject to linear constraint, using quadratic programming/minimization in Python

Tags: python, linear-algebra, cvxopt, quadratic-programming

I need to solve the following quadratic minimization subject to linear inequality constraint;

[image]

Where

||ξ|| is the Euclidean norm of ξ,

ξ and vk are vectors

and λk is a scalar.

I think this can be done with CVXOPT, but I don't have any experience with quadratic minimization so I am a bit lost, some help or just pointers would be greatly appreciated!.

solve ξ∗ = argmin||ξ|| subject to z.T ξ ≥ −λk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cvxopt.solvers.qp`  seems to be able to solve

1/2 x<sup>T</sup> P x + q<sup>T</sup> x

subject to

Ax ≤ B

For your case,

||ξ||<sup>2</sup> = ξ<sup>2</sup> = ξ<sup>T</sup> I ξ = 1/2 ξ<sup>T</sup> (2 × I) ξ + **0** x ξ

where I is an identity matrix. So your P and q are (2 × I) and **0** and A = -z_k, b = l_k.

With the given `z_k` and `l_k` (λ), you can solve matrix inequality by

```
import numpy
from cvxopt import matrix

P  = matrix([
    [2., 0., 0.],
    [0., 2., 0.],
    [0., 0., 2.]
])

q   = matrix([[0., 0., 0.]])

z_k = matrix([
    [1.],
    [2.],
    [3.]
])

l_k = matrix([4.])

from cvxopt import solvers

sol = solvers.qp(P, q, -z_k, l_k)

print(sol['x'])                 # argmin ξ
print(sol['primal objective'])  # min ξ^2
```

Check [this](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.867/wiki/images/a/a7/Qp-cvxopt.pdf).

If you need `min ||ξ||`, the norm:

```
import math
print(math.sqrt(sol['primal objective']))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, just one thing I don't understand; isn't ξT I ξ = ||ξ||^2 ???. Maybe it doesn't matter because minimizing the square of the norm is equivalent to minimizing the norm???.

Comment: @Vinzent Ah, sorry about that. Since it is not `argmin` but `min`, you are right. You may square root the result.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by argmin, but the problem IS actually formulated like this;

"solve ξ∗ = argmin||ξ|| subject to z.T ξ ≥ −λk"

But I can't square-root the result because the result is ξ, I need to find ξ such that ||ξ|| is minimal, not such that ||ξ||^2 is minimal, am I misunderstanding something?...

Comment: `argmin_x` means the argument `x` minimizing `f(x)`. `min_x` means the minimum `f(x)` by the given `x`.

Comment: Okay yes I thought so.. So is it then correct to minimize ||ξ||^2 rather than ||ξ|| as in your answer?.. I guess the value of ξ than makes ||ξ||^2 minimal will also be the value of ξ that makes ||ξ|| minimal right?

Comment: @Vinzent As long as it is `argmin`, one that minimizing `||ξ||^2` is equal to another that minimizing `√||ξ||^2` = `||ξ||`.

Comment: @Vinzent If it is `min`, `min ||ξ||` is equal to `min √||ξ||^2`

Comment: Yes that makes sense, thank you again!.. And then I guess since in my problem I need z.T ξ ≥ −λk then A = -z.T and b = λk .. ie. I can just negate both sides of the inequality to make >= into <= ???

Comment: @Vinzent It seems so according to the reference. Also, I made an edit to find `min ||ξ||`. If fine, please accept the answer.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, thank you very much for your help!..

Comment: @Vinzent Thank you too!

Comment: I think it would be best if you edit the line "sol = solvers.qp(P, q, z_k, l_k)" to say "sol = solvers.qp(P, q, -z_k, l_k)" to reflect that z_k needs to be negated.. in case others come across the question.

Comment: @Vinzent Nice, haha. Take my upvote, thanks!